# Interactive Table View Header with check boxes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox, sectionheader

I designed the header of the tableview in such a way that it is being interactive through check boxes made from button by changing images. When I clicked a check box it is checked and unchecked correctly.

What I want is when I click the check box, if it gets checked the the rest of the two checkboxes should get unchecked automatically. Below is the code.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let identifierHeader:String = "SavedCallHeader"

    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifierHeader) as! SavedCallHeader




    headerCell.checkBox_PlannedisOn = checkBox_PlannedisOn
    headerCell.checkBox_unPlannedisOn = checkBox_unPlannedisOn
    headerCell.checkBox_BothisOn = checkBox_BothisOn

    headerCell.callBackForReload = { [weak self] (type,isCalled) -> Void in
        print("is called Planned = \(type)")
        print("is called Planned = \(isCalled)")

        if type == "Planned"{
            //Planned CallBack
            if isCalled == true {
                 print("Planned selected")
                self?.fetchPlannedData()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()


            } else {

                self?.DeSelect()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                print("Planned Not selected")
            }
            self?.checkBox_PlannedisOn = isCalled
        }else if type == "UnPlanned"{
            //UnPlanned CallBack 
            if isCalled == true {
                print("UnPlanned Selected")
                self?.fetchUnPlannedData()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
                self?.DeSelect()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                print("UnPlanned Not selected")
            }
            self?.checkBox_unPlannedisOn = isCalled
        }else{ 
            //Both CallBack 
            if isCalled == true { 
                print("Both Selected")
                self?.fetchDate()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
                 self?.DeSelect()
                 self?.tableView.reloadData()
                print("both Not selected")
            }
             self?.checkBox_BothisOn = isCalled
        } 

    }

    return headerCell

}
```

and this is the custom header class

```
   class SavedCallHeader : UITableViewCell{

    var callBackForReloadPlanned : ((Bool) -> ())?
    var callBackForReloadBoth : ((Bool) -> ())?
    var callBackForReloadUnPlanned : ((Bool) -> ())?

    var NameOfOnStatus : ((String) -> ())?

    var AnyOneIsOn:Bool = true

    var callBackForReload : ((String,Bool) -> ())?

   // var checkBox_PlannedisOn:Bool = false
   // var checkBox_BothisOn:Bool = true
   // var checkBox_unPlannedisOn:Bool = false

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var PlannedBoxBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var BothBoxBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var unPlannedBoxBtn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    var checkBox_PlannedisOn:Bool = false {
        didSet{
            self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            if checkBox_PlannedisOn{
                self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
              //  self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
               //  self.unPlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }

    var checkBox_BothisOn:Bool = false {
        didSet{
            self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            if checkBox_BothisOn{
                self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
               //  self.unPlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
               // self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }

    var checkBox_unPlannedisOn:Bool = false {
        didSet{
            self.unPlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            if checkBox_unPlannedisOn{
                self.unPlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
              //  self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
              //   self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func PlannedCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if checkBox_PlannedisOn == false {
          //  self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            checkBox_PlannedisOn = true
            print("i'm finally here proper click!",checkBox_PlannedisOn)
            self.callBackForReload!("Planned",true)


        }else {
          //  self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            checkBox_PlannedisOn = false
            print("i'm finally heress proper click!",checkBox_PlannedisOn)
            self.callBackForReload!("Planned",false) 
        }  

          }

    @IBAction func BothCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {


          if checkBox_BothisOn == false {
          //  self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            checkBox_BothisOn = true
            self.callBackForReload!("Both",true)


        }else {
            // self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
          //  self.BothBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            checkBox_BothisOn = false 
            self.callBackForReload!("Both",false)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func UnPlannedCheckBox(_ sender: Any) {


        if checkBox_unPlannedisOn == false {
           // self.unPlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            checkBox_unPlannedisOn = true
            self.callBackForReload!("UnPlanned",true)


        }else {
           // self.unPlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            checkBox_unPlannedisOn = false
            self.callBackForReload!("UnPlanned",false) 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set tag for each button and when you click on particular button then deselect other buttons based on tags.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable to keep track of the selected checkbox and update its value depending on that variable's status.

Inside `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` modify the code like

```
var selectedCheckBoxIndex:Int?



headerCell.checkBox_PlannedisOn = selectedCheckBoxIndex == 0 ? true : false
    headerCell.checkBox_unPlannedisOn = selectedCheckBoxIndex == 1 ? true : false
    headerCell.checkBox_BothisOn = selectedCheckBoxIndex == 2 ? true : false


if type == "Planned"{
            //Planned CallBack
            if isCalled == true {
                 print("Planned selected")
                self?.fetchPlannedData()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
               selectedCheckBoxIndex = 0

            } else {

                self?.DeSelect()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                print("Planned Not selected")
            }
            self?.checkBox_PlannedisOn = isCalled
        }else if type == "UnPlanned"{
            //UnPlanned CallBack 
            if isCalled == true {
                print("UnPlanned Selected")
                self?.fetchUnPlannedData()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                selectedCheckBoxIndex = 1
            } else {
                self?.DeSelect()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                print("UnPlanned Not selected")
            }
            self?.checkBox_unPlannedisOn = isCalled
        }else{ 
            //Both CallBack 
            if isCalled == true { 
                print("Both Selected")
                self?.fetchDate()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                selectedCheckBoxIndex = 2
            } else {
                 self?.DeSelect()
                 self?.tableView.reloadData()
                print("both Not selected")
            }
             self?.checkBox_BothisOn = isCalled
        } 

    }
```

Comment: WORKED! Thanks Alotttt!